# How can I display the decimals of a number in VLOOKUP formula?

Tags: excel, decimal, vlookup

I have this formula in my Sheet 1 returning a value from Data sheet

```
="** "&(VLOOKUP(D9,Data!A2:B121,2,FALSE)&" **")
```

In the Data sheet I have the number 6,524.60

But in my current sheet when VLOOKUP the number displays like

```
** 6805.3 **
```

I need to display it as

```
** 6,805.30 **
```

Is there any way of doing that? My macro sheet already has the SpellNumber VBA on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Text function for that as below in your function.

```
="** "&(TEXT(VLOOKUP(A1;A1:B1;2;FALSE);"#,#.00")&" **")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solving this for me so quickly! @ali

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for TEXT() and I would recommand to use CONCATENATE:

```
=CONCATENATE("** ",TEXT(VLOOKUP(D9,Data!A2:B121,2,FALSE),"$#,##0.00")," **")
```